# Agregar PDF a un form Visual Basic.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, .net

Mi problema es como puedo agregar un PDF con información a un Form.
Lo que he visto en internet es como cargar un PDF desde un Form con un button y las personas lo cargar, pero lo que yo quiero hacer es que cuando se abra el Form ya me aparezca el PDF que yo carge en el programa porque es un unico PDF con informacion sobre el programa que estoy creando.
Espero puedan entender mi duda y me puedan ayudar.
Gracias.

Comment: podrias usar la libreria de acrobat, es muy sencillo, pero si el pdf es el mismo siempre, por que no incrustarlo como imagen png o algo similar?

Comment: Podrías hacerlo a través de un `WebBrowser`, navega con él a la ruta de tu archivo (absoluta si es en red o relativa si lo copiarás con la instalación). Todo esto hazlo en el `Load` de tu formulario para que se ejecute al iniciarlo y listo. Sería como `WebBrowser1.Navigate(RutaDeTuPDF)`

Comment: Luis Carlos Donado Avella he usada el .dll de Acrobat pero no se como hacer para que me quede siempre el pdf y con una imagen imposible porque son varias paginas de pdf. Igual gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: CharlieMR gracias por tu comentario, luego voy a probar eso que me dices y ver si me funciona, saludos.